# Async queue hanging up with requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request

I have a function that loops through content and calls back on the result. That result I then add to an async queue with a concurrency of 1. I then make a request with the content supplied  and stream the result to a file. But for some reason, the queue seems to hang up after three calls and I cannot figure out why.

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

var queue = async.queue(function (url, callback) { 

  var file = fs.createWriteStream('./images/' + url.split('/')[5])
  var image = request(url);
  image.pipe(file);
  file.on('close', function() {
    callback('done')
  })
},1);

getUrls(query, function(e, url) {
  queue.push(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
});

queue.drain = function() {
    console.log('all items have been processed');
}


Assume all files are just random images like this 
http://pandodaily.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/google-in-bed-w-mercenaries-n-military-e1395865855795.jpg?w=900&h=499
```

Also assume that `getUrls` is spitting out 5 - 10 urls into the queue.

So basically, the first couple of requests make it through and pipe to a file, but for some reason after that is hangs and never hits the drain function.

Answer (score 0):

Try listening to `finish` instead of `close` before calling the callback. `close` is for the Readable stream, where `finish` is for the Writable stream.

`file.on('finish', function() {
  callback('done');
})`

Refer to the API docs for more details:
http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish